# como acceder a metodo de controlador de cakephp mediante axios desde un metodo de vuejs

Tags: vue.js, axios, cakephp

en mi proyecto quiero acceder a un metodo en un controlador cakephp desde otro metodo que esta en un vuejs, 'modulo.php' es el controlador y 'comunica' es el metodo o accion de cakephp al que necesito acceder.
El tema es que no he podido dar con la URL necesaria para acceder al metodo en el controlador de cakephp por lo que si alguien me pudiera cooperar en este tema se lo agradeceria.

```
    obtieneData() {

        axios
        .get('/Modulo.php/comunica')
        .catch(error => {
            alert('Error en recuperacion de datos');
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);

        });
    },
```